# Unique Array and make it as JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like this:
myArray = {"a:10","a:5","a:25","b:10","b:25",b:20","c:5","c:30","c:15"}. How do i construct a json object like this using javascript or jquery?

{"a":["10","5","25"],"b":["10","25","20"],"c":["5","30","15"]}

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945735/condensing-a-collection-of-objects-using-underscore-js

Comment: it is an array of strings, I could able to get the unique elements of the array if I can split with : each string.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
var myArray = ["a:10","a:5","a:25","b:10","b:25","b:20","c:5","c:30","c:15"],
    output = {};

for (var i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++){
    var item = myArray[i].split(":");
    var key = item[0];
    var value = item[1];
    var array = output[key];
    if (!array){
        array = [];
        output[key] = array
    }
    array.push(value);
}
```

Or a more functional way:

```
myArray.map(function(i){
        var parts = i.split(":");
        return {key:parts[0], value: parts[1]}
    })
    .reduce(function(p,c){
        var array = p[c.key];
        if (!array){
            array = [];
            p[c.key] = array
        }
        array.push(c.value);
        return p;
    },{});
```